# Is there a way in Camunda REST API to retrieve task’s form field property?

Tags: rest, camunda, camunda-modeler

Camunda Modeler can let us set form field properties for tasks. I would like to use this feature to store some information for frontend input field rendering, e.g. inputtype=file for file upload selector.

Unfortunately, I found that the REST API `/task/{taskid}/form-variables` is not returing me such information and I have no other way to retrieve these information.

Any advice on how to get back these properties of task? Or any suggestion on how to store information for task that can let me retrieve them back through REST API?

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no way to get camunda task form field property as of now, this was not taken in under improvements as there weren't sufficient votes as evidence to show the feature necessity . Related camunda task: https://jira.camunda.com/browse/CAM-14182

Comment: Thanks @RahulRanjan, yes I know. Because the ticket was opened by me.   hahaha